# How to chain Modifiers replaceText & applyInlineStyle method in draft.js

Tags: reactjs, rich-text-editor, draftjs

I've a requirement where I've to set custom key commands for applying custom styles & I've to remove key commands after pressing space from the editor & defined inline style should be applied afterward for applying styling I'm using Modifiers  applyInlineStyle methods & for clearing the command I'm using Modifiers replacetext method in draft.js, but only replacetext method is working but inline styling not getting applied
Here is the code snippet

```
  const newContentState = Modifier.replaceText(
    currentContent,
    currentSelection.merge({
      anchorOffset: 0,
      focusOffset: 2,
    }),
    "",
    null,
    null
  );
  const newContentStateWithStyle = Modifier.applyInlineStyle(
    newContentState,
    newContentState.getSelectionAfter(),
    "RED_TEXT"
  );

  const newEditorState = EditorState.push(
    editorState,
    newContentStateWithStyle,
    "change-inline-style"
  );
```

Please help me identify the issue, Thanks!